# Categorize list with awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

```
#!/bin/bash

PASTE=$(xclip -o)

curl -s https://website.com/$PASTE | dos2unix | grep -A3 '<td class="hidden-xs"' | sed 's/<[^>]*//1g; s/>//g; s/  //g; s/\\r//g; /^$/d; s/--/-/g; s/&#246;/ö/g; s/&#252;/ü/g; s/&#231;/ç/g' | awk '!/^Genel/ || !f++'
```

It generates this result:

```
General
hit
definition 1
-
General
hit
definition 2
-
... 
-
Idiom
hit the sack
Definition 
-
Idiom
hit the buffers
Definition 1
-
Idiom
hit the buffers
Definition 2
```

I am trying to categorize it, and make the result like this:

```
General
hit
definition 1
definition 2
definition ...
-
Idiom
hit the sack
Definition 
-
hit the buffers
Definition 1
Definition 2
```

Comment: I suggest double quote "$PASTE" to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: Yea once i had a problem there.
curl -s "https://example.com/translation/${PASTE}"
i have changed it to this. Do you think any adjustment needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
$0=="General" || $0=="Idiom"{
  type=$0;  getline
  group=$0; getline

  key=type","group  
  if (key in b){
    b[key]=b[key]"\n"$0
  }
  else {
    if (type=="General" && !isfirstgeneral){
      type=type"\n"; isfirstgeneral=1
    }
    else if (type=="Idiom" && !isfirstidiom){
      type=type"\n"; isfirstidiom=1
    }
    else {
      type=""
    }
    a[++cnt]=key
    b[key]=type group"\n"$0
  }
}
END{
  for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++){
    print b[a[i]]
    if (i<cnt) print "-"
  }
}' file
```

If a line is `General` or `Idiom`, save this line as `type` and get the next two lines (called `group` and the "definition" as `$0`).

Two arrays are used as a trick to prevent `awk`'s possible chaotic ordering of array elements when looped:

- array `a` with integer key stores the key of array `b` consisting of the `type` and the following `group` line
- array `b` holds the collected string for a given key

When the combined key for array `b` doesn't exist, create two new array elements. The `type` strings are only saved the first time they are encountered 
(if this was a mistake in the output, then remove the `if-else if-else`-block and replace `b[key]=type group"\n"$0` with `b[key]=type"\n"group"\n"$0`).

If the key exists, append the "definition" string to the existing array value.

In the `END` part, print the values of array `b` using the order of array `a` followed by a separator line.

(I saved your input as file `file`, but you can pipe the output of your `curl` command into this awk script if you want.)

Output:

```
General
hit
definition 1
definition 2
-
Idiom
hit the sack
Definition
-
hit the buffers
Definition 1
Definition 2
```

---

**Update**

To use a list of categories, add your categories to a text file, one line per category.

Example `categories.txt`:

```
General
Idiom
Computer
What ever
```

Change the script to

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
  cat[$0]; next
}
$0 in cat{
  type=$0;  getline
  group=$0; getline

  key=type","group  
  if (key in b){
    b[key]=b[key]"\n"$0
  }
  else {
    a[++cnt]=key
    b[key]=group"\n"$0
  }
}
END{
  for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++){
    # print first occurrence of category
    catname=a[i]
    sub(/,.*/, "", catname)
    if (catname in cat){
      print catname
      delete cat[catname]
    }

    print b[a[i]]
    if (i<cnt) print "-"
  }
}' categories.txt file
```

Comment: It works fabolously :) Thank you so much

Can we add more category to your script?
I have just encounter if the word's category falls into "Computer", it doesnt generate any output.

Comment: Are "General" and "Idiom" categories? If yes, then you would have to add "Computer" to the second line as `$0=="General" || $0=="Idiom" || $0=="Computer"{` and another `else if` under the existing `else if` to print only the first match of this category like `else if (type=="Computer" && !isfirstcomputer){ type=type"\n"; isfirstcomputer=1 }`.

Comment: It is working :) I couldnt find it, if it wasnt for you

Yes they have more than 60 categories. I made a list for it in text file (categories.txt):

"Common Usage",
"General",
"Idioms",
"Proverb",
"Economy",
"Medical"
without quotation marks and comma. 

Can we make awk read from this file with a while loop and put it in if statement?
and can we put them in order as in categories.txt? But i think it has been already doing, becase it follows the order of the webpage.

Comment: Added, see the update. I also added a bugfix to the original script.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cheeky use of `awk` associative arrays.....

```
awk '$0=="General"||$0=="Idiom"{
    cat=$0;getline; def=$0; getline;
    (cat=="General")?gen[def]=gen[def]"\n"$0:idi[def]=idi[def]"\n"$0
}END{
    print "General";for (g in gen) print g, gen[g]"\n-";
    print "Idioms";for (i in idi) print i, idi[i]"\n-"
}' file
```

Output:

```
General
hit 
definition 1
definition 2
-
Idioms
hit the buffers 
Definition 1
Definition 2
-
hit the sack 
Definition
-
```

This assumes of course that all of your definitions are "one liners"

**More categories** Without worrying about the order that categories come out in.....

```
awk '{
    cat=$0; getline; phr=$0;getline; def=$0; getline;
    cats[cat];defs[phr]=cat;txt[phr]=txt[phr]"\n"def
}END{
    for (c in cats) {
        print c":"; for (d in defs) {
            if (defs[d]==c) print d, txt[d]"\n-"
        }
    }
}' file
```

Input

```
General
hit
Strike a blow.
-
General
hit
A successful search result. 
-
Idiom
hit the sack
Go to bed.
-
Idiom
hit the buffers
Reach the end of the line.
-
Idiom
hit the buffers
Reach the limit.
-
Bananas
Banana
A Banana
```

Output

```
Bananas:
Banana 
A Banana
-
Idiom:
hit the buffers 
Reach the end of the line.
Reach the limit.
-
hit the sack 
Go to bed.
-
General:
hit 
Strike a blow.
A successful search result. 
-
```

If you want to control the category output in the same sequence you find them then you will either need to enumerate them or create a string separated by (say) `|` for all of the `cat`s then `split` it into an enumerated array and then use it as an iterator over the other arrays.

This one does rely on a 4 line sequence in the entries.

Comment: It is so cheeky :) it works like randomly.
can we add more category to it? 
When i run script it generates more category than i expected.

Law, Computer Science ...

Comment: It works but one more issue is remained:
when category has two words, for example,   spoken language and trade/economy. it cant handle this categories. 
btw it works so awesome. i have splitted the "file" so numberization isnt a problem. lets say it finds "usage with other words" and split the text from there. i just need to find how to do it with sed and delete that line. it becomes the first line and second line "-"

Comment: Odd, Double words and those with `/` working fine for me. Update the sample text to include a problem file and I will test from here.

Comment: Technic: \n Genel: at the beginning. It is not a big deal. It works :)

Comment: You are right it is not a problem. It is working. Just first two line, for example Technic: \n General, but it shows technic definitions in the right place, under General, and that's correct. So, it is not a big deal. It works :)